# One of 2 domain servers went down and now I can't connect to SQL Server on the other

Tags: sql-server, connectivity

I have:

- 2 AD Domain controllers - one running Windows Server 2008r2 and the other Windows Server 2016.
- FSMO roles are all on the Windows Server 2008r2
- Windows Server 2016 is only online during a convention where we need quick backup
- I disconnected the Windows Server 2016 server from the network to simulate the Windows Server 2008r2 going down
- I connected a workstation in a separate physical network to the 2016 and I get network errors trying to connect to SQL Server (both SQL Servers are version 2014) from the workstation

The error I get is:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing ... Verify instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections (it is) error 26

I can connect to the server on the 2016 using SSMS from the server itself but not from SSMS on the workstation

SQL Server Browser is running on the server on Windows 2016, and I can ping the Windows 2016 server from the workstation.

Both SQL Servers are running instances called `<servername>\sqlexpress`. When I browse in the connection box on SSMS for network server on the 2016 windows server the network server comes back with just `<servername>`.

I re-verified that the running server is running the named instance.

I have rebooted both machines and logged in as an AD Administrator

I have run out of things to try.

Comment: Take a look at the [SQL Server Error Log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/configuration-manager/viewing-the-sql-server-error-log?view=sql-server-ver16) to see what the server says the problem is.  The error you listed is the one shown to the client, and it doesn't contain the state code that will allow you to determine the problem.

Comment: "Both SQL Servers are running instances called `<servername>\sqlexpress`.": by your description I assume you're trying to connect to the server by using the server name, but since you removed the 2016 server from the original network you might have isolated it from your DNS server and it's not resolving the server name. Have you tried to connect using `<server IP>\sqlexpress`?

Comment: Ronaldo: I should have mentioned I thought of that and tried the server IP route and that didn't work. I also have the isolated computer running DNS as well and tried ping <servername> which resolved perfectly. 
Hannah, Unfortunately I ran out of time to decommission that server so it's gone now but I'll be doing this again and I'll be testing it again early in the convention setup and I'll keep your suggestion. I had not thought that since the message was "couldn't find the server" that there would be any message server side.

Comment: The SQL Server log suggestion can still be verified since the logs are kept on the server until the file is recycled. If there's no log, then your assumption was correct and the workstation wasn't even reaching the server.

Comment: @Ronaldo I guess I wasn't clear.  That server has been decommissioned and wiped so I'll have to try this again next year and earlier